# Adding an attribute to json from joined table

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, jbuilder

I am trying to provide a json that would contain information coming from two tables:MenuItem, and Partner.

In the json below "partner_number" would actually come from the partner table.

```
{
    "id": 33,
    "partner_id": 12,
    "partner_number":234526,
    "item_price": "15.0",
    "item_type": "Main-meal",
    "name": "Teriyaki Chicken Donburi",
    "description": "Three eggs with cilantro, tomatoes, onions, avocados and melted Emmental cheese. With a side of roasted potatoes, and your choice of toast or croissant."
  },
```

This is the method I built, trying to add the information into the results.

```
def index
    @menu_items = policy_scope(MenuItem).joins(:partner)
    @menu_items.each do|item|
      item[:partner_number] = item.partner.partner_number
    end
  end
```

But it gives me this error message

ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError in Api::V1::MenuItemsController#index
can't write unknown attribute `partner_number`

Is there a way to do it from the controller ?

Comment: Item doesn't have a partner_number.  You can add a delegate to your item model...```delegate :partner_number, to: :partner``` and you shouldn't have to do anything else.  If you just want it for json, then you'll need to override the serialization.

Comment: is it as simple as using something like "item[:partner_number]" to access the number instead of "item.partner_number"

Answer (score 0):

`join` method not load relationships into results. You should use [`includes`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#includes) who make a join AND load relationships

```rb
@menu_items = policy_scope(MenuItem).includes(:partner)
```